# MiniMax Starting Position

Tags: artificial-intelligence, greedy, minimax

I have built an AI to play the Mancala game. I have implemented a minimax search however it always loses when it starts 2nd against a local greedy AI. The minimax is only able to beat the local greedy player when minimax starts first. Is there an explanation to this or is there a way to be able to beat the local greedy AI with some generic algorithm?

Comment: You may be using reverse min/max players when changing sides. Maybe this question should be on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sounds like you search "in the wrong" direction, i.e. your AI is trying to make the other win. That's probably because the root of your minimax tree is (like when the AI starts first) the initial game state. It should be the game state in which the AI is first allowed to make a move.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the rules (and simplicity) of your mancala game, it might be that a greedy algorithm is nearly as good as minimax. In that case, the player who wins is the player who goes first. From my experience, strategic mancala game play is usually quite susceptible to simple strategies and greedy done the right way (for breaking ties) may very well be enough.

To make sure your minimax is indeed correct, try allowing it to play against a random player. It should easily beat them by starting first or second. If your minimax is set to "always be first", it could be a bug in your algorithm or score computations.